# Need auto separator in input field while typing in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a number input field which only limits 13 each. After the first 5 numbers it separates auto-fill '-' and then the next 13 will be the same.

input state: `const [num, handleNum] = useState('')`

I wrote this function but when I remove the number after the separator, It can’t be deleted.

```
const handleAutoFilling = val => {
        handleNum(val)

        if (val.length === 5 || val.length === 13) {
            handleNum(`${val}-`)
        }
    }
```

```
<Input placeholder='CNIC' inputType='text'
    onChange={value => handleAutoFilling(value)}
    value={num}
/>
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: [https://j7k2z.csb.app/]
@palaѕн